# How to underline the echo row name for only LastName?

Tags: php, html

```
echo "<tr>" ."<td>".$row["MemberID"]."</td>"  ."<td>".$row["FirstName"]."</td>"  ."<td>".$row["LastName"]."</td>" ."<td>".$row["Country"]."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<tr>" ."<td>".$row["MemberID"]."</td>"  ."<td>".$row["FirstName"]."</td>"  ."<td><u>".$row["LastName"]."</u></td>" ."<td>".$row["Country"]."</td>";
```

That should do the trick, to do this using css you would use the following

```
text-decoration: underline;
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you could use CSS `nth-of-type`

```css
.a-table tr td:nth-of-type(3) {
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<table class="a-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```